# Replace some strings in multiple files?

Tags: bash

I need to use sed command to replace this string

```
)/2
```

to this

```
) // 2
```

from all files with .xml in all directories ...
I have try this command

```
find ./ -type f -name '/home/Desktop/Skins/*.xml' -exec sed -i -e 's|)/2|) // 2|g' {} \;
```

But nothing change and I have got this error !!

Comment: You forgot to add the error!

Comment: Even without seeing the error, I am pretty sure that `-name '/home/Desktop/Skins/*.xml'` is the problem, and not `sed`.

Comment: Probably you want for `sed -i 's|)/2|) // 2|g' ~/Desktop/Skins/*.xml`

Comment: Already I have tried that method as I got error `*.xml: No such file or directory`. Because the main directory include more folders like (test, game. movies ...) and each directory include xml file

Comment: Don't use a regexp metachar like `|` as a delimiter as that obfuscates your code at best. If you don't want to use the default `/` then use some other char that's also always literal such as `:` or `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like that

If you have not subdirectory.

```
$ cd /home/Desktop/Skins/
$ sed -i -e 's|)/2|) // 2|g' *.xml
$ cat 1.xml
) // 2
$ cat 2.xml
) // 2

$ cat 3.xml
) // 2
)/3
)/4
```

Comment: You can change the find command to  : find /home/Desktop/Skins/ -type f -name '*.xml'  -exec sed -i -e 's|)/2|) // 2|g' {} \;

Comment: work fine in directory and subdirectory :  find /home/Desktop/Skins/  -type f -name '*.xml' -exec sed -i -e 's|)/2|) // 2|g' {} +

Comment: Thank you ... Works great .... `find /home/Desktop/Skins/ -type f -name '*.xml' -exec sed -i -e 's|)/2|) // 2|g' {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo ')/2' | sed '\~)/2~s~/~ && ~'
) // 2
```